# ListView not calling ItemCreated after postback

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, listview, databound

I have an asp:ListView where I want to filter the items based on a property of the contained DataItem

I want to set the item invisible unless the specified property (FieldName) has the value I'm looking for.

```
 protected override void ItemCreated(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, FieldName).ToString() != FieldValue)
        {
            e.Item.Visible = SetVisible;
        }
    }
```

But on postback, the DataItem is null, and I am unable to restore the previous state. My expectation was, that the Listview would be able to keep the visible property in Viewstate, but it doesn't. I could call Listview.Databind, but the listview is used to select items with a checkbox, and this selection is lost on databind.

How can I restore the items visibility to its first state after databind?

Comment: DataItem will always be null unless you rebind the ListView with data.

Comment: But if I rebind, the viewstate for the checked state of the checkboxes is lost.

Comment: Yes you are right.  So you are in a catch 22, however....

Answer (score 0):

Put your logic in the OnItemDataBound event instead. The data is always null because at the time the item is created, it has not yet been bound.

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario, you are checking an additional field.  Store that additional field in the DataKeyNames collection, and pull the value from there.  That value is stored in viewstate, so it will be available across postbacks.

HTH.